# MySQL query - multiple JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

I have a database sort of like a dictionary. Essentially, there are six tables:

**words_a** (id_a, word_a) contains all words of language A

**words_b** (id_b, word_b) contains all words of language B

**words** (id, id_a, id_b) connects words of language A and their corresponding translation to language B

**categories** (id, cat_id) assigns categories to every worda-wordb-relationship from *words*-table

Now what I want to do is get all translations in a certain category.

I choose a category id (cat_id) and get all the word-word-relationships (id) in that category, then I get the two corresponding word IDs (id_a and id_b) for those relationships:

```
    SELECT id_a, id_b
    FROM words, (
        SELECT *
        FROM `categories`
        WHERE cat_id =6
    ) AS temp
    WHERE words.id = temp.id
```

This gives me a table with the IDs of all words in language A and the IDs of their corresponding translations to language B in category 6. Now I need the actual words to the IDs.

```
SELECT word_a, word_b FROM words_a,words_b, (
    SELECT id_a,id_b 
    FROM words, (
        SELECT * 
        FROM categories 
        WHERE cat_id=6 ) AS t 
    WHERE words.id = t.id ) AS temp 
WHERE ??? )
```

What should my where-clause look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

> SELECT word_a, word_b FROM words_a,words_b,word,categories WHERE
>   words.id = categories.id and word_a.id_a = words.id_a and word_b.id_b
>   = words.id_b AND categories.cat_id = 6

This creates a join over all 4 tables instead of using subqueries.